# generate wcf server code from wsdl files

Tags: wcf, servicecontract

Greetings, I would like to generate some contract based on wsdl file. I used svcutil but I suspect it generated it wrong as all contract methods have void returned type. Is there any tool for this purpose?

EDIT:
here is the wsdl file:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://dantek.com.pl/EDItEUR/EDItX/LibraryBookSupply/WebService/CustomerService/20100611/ServiceContract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" targetNamespace="http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/Imports">
      <xsd:import namespace="http http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/ServiceContract" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="CustomerService_ProcessMethod_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ProcessMethod" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CustomerService_ProcessMethod_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ProcessMethodResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
>
  <wsdl:portType name="CustomerService">
    <wsdl:operation name="ProcessShipNotice">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action=" http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/ProcessMethod" message="tns:CustomerService_ProcessMethod_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action=" http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/ProcessMethod" message="tns:CustomerService_ProcessMethod_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And the contract created

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface CustomerService
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/CustomerService/ProcessMethod”, ReplyAction = " http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/CustomerService/ProcessMethodResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    void ProcessMethod(ProcessMethodRequest request);
```

I don't want to have ProcessMethod returned type void but rather ProcessMethodResponse type. How can I achieve it?

EDIT2: Here's my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://myTargetNamespece/ServiceContract" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
     targetNamespace="http://myTargetNamespace/ServiceContract" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ProcessMethod">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:ProcessMethodRequest" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="ProcessMethodRequest" abstract="true" />
  <xs:complexType name="ProcessMethodRequestWithPayload"/>
  <xs:element name="ProcessMethodResponse">
    <xs:complexType />
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: No, svcutil would be the right tool for the job. You need to be more specific about your problems, I guess... can you show us part of the WSDL and the code generated from it??

Comment: OK, it seems your data types are defined elsewhere - there must be a XSD file somewhere that contains the objects in the `http://mytargetNamespace/ServiceContract/ServiceContract` namespace. Did you include that in your call to svcutil ??

Comment: yes I have included in my call to svcutil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generated operation contract is correct. You WSDL specifies request/response operation (= two-way) with empty response. ProcessMethodResponse element is wrapper element for the response message but it does not contain any subelements = void response.

If you want to return ProcessMethodResponse you have to use message contracts. You can instruct svcutil to use message contracts by /mc or /messageContract switch.